# table content_type_answer show to merge it with node table

Tags: database

I have a `{content_type_answers}` and this table doesn't has a title row, how can i merge it with `{node}` to get node titles?

```
$result = db_query("SELECT {node}.title, {node}.nid FROM {content_type_answers} cta, node WHERE {cta}.nid = {node}.nid");
while($node = db_fetch_object($result) {
    $nodes[] = array($node->title, $node->nid);
}
```

Question: how can i select {node}.title from table {content_type_answers} if in this table no title row at all?

Comment: the title $node->title that you have in your code is the title of the node in content_type_answers. You don't need to have a column title in your content_type_answers table.

Comment: Have checked my code above? it is correct? after {content_type_answers} cta (it is table name?), node (it is talbe name?)

Comment: $result = db_query("SELECT node.title, node.nid FROM {content_type_answers} cta, {node} WHERE cta.nid = node.nid");
while($node = db_fetch_object($result) {
    $nodes[] = array($node->title, $node->nid);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
    $q = db_query("
SELECT node.title, node.nid 
FROM content_type_answers cta, node 
WHERE cta.nid = node.nid");
    while ($r = db_fetch_array($q)) {
      $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print theme('table', $header, $rows);
```

Comment: This is a alias in order to don't rewrite content_type_answers

Comment: check my edited question ↑

Comment: You should really use the curly brace syntax in queries to allow Drupal to handle a table prefix.  Using proper INNER JOIN syntax rather that the FROM/WHERE variant is also advisable.